# Background Cover for image stored in mysql

Tags: php, css, image, data-uri

I have an image stored in a database that I'm trying to stretch to width and height of div, I can get the width to 100% but can't get the height to do the same.

I'd like to use background cover but that wont work as I'm not getting my image via background: url() in css

The code has been tried with different variations but currently is:

```
<div id="postimave">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($thumb) ?>" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stretch the image to the height and width in pixels (px) of the div might not be the best easy bit should work

Comment: The div the image is in is a percentage of screen size, so the number of pixels is not known. If it comes to it I suppose I can state the pixel height rather than use a percentage but I'd like to find a way to work with the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover;` can only be applied to a `background-image` definition in CSS. You're saying that you can't use it that way. Is there are specific reason? In general it does work this way:

```
<div id="postimave" style="background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($thumb); ?>)">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#postimave{
    background-size:cover;
    /* Add your desired width and height */
}
```

Using the `img`-element you can set the `width: 100%;` which will fill the space horizontally. Other options would be to resize/crop the image via PHP or using JavaScript for recreating the  cover-effect.