# How to define an image from the database stored in binary as a div background image?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an image that is stored in the database in **binary form**. I have rescued this image (with a select) and would like to insert it as a div's **background image**. I can only enter it as src of an img.

**How to Store in Database:**

```html
<?php

$foto = $_FILES['image']['name'];

if($this->__get('image') != "")
{
  $binary = file_get_contents($this->__get('foto')); 
  $query = "UPDATE usuarios SET image = :image, name = :name" ;
  $query .= "WHERE id = :id";
    
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindValue(':image', $binary);
  $stmt->bindValue(':name', $this->__get('name')); 
  $stmt->bindValue(':id', $this->__get('id'));
  $stmt->execute();  
}

?>
```

**Part I enter as src of an img. (
it's working)**

```html
<?php
      
function dataURI($bin)
{
  return 'data: image/gif;base64,'.base64_encode( $bin );
}    
     
?>

  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" id="div-foto-usuario">
      <?php        
      if(!empty($this->view->info_usuario['image']))
      {          

     $image = dataURI($this->view->info_usuario['image']);
   
     echo "<img id='img-image-user' class='mr-2 border border-secondary' src='$image' style='border-radius:50%;width:120px; height:120px;'>";    
    }
    else
    {
     echo "<img id='img-image-user' class='mr-2 border border-secondary' src='/img/user.jpg' style='border-radius:50%;width:120px; height:120px;'>";
    }
    ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**I would like to insert in the div background-image below: (The problem)**

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $foto;?>);">
  </div>
</div>
```

- I tried to echo the variable that contains the image inside the url (), but it didn't work out.
- Generated Page HTML Code:[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d0jyaup/)
- I am brazilian. I don't speak english. I used the google translate.

Comment: Note there is also https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @miken32 , I know. I did not find an answer on the site in Portuguese.

Comment: Ok, I was just making sure you know about it in case you're more comfortable in a native language. It's good you found your answer here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<div id="postimave" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image; ?>')">Some text
</div>
```

Comment: oops ;p [postimave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001493/661872)

Comment: @nbk, Did not work. I think I already did that in the dataURI ($ bin) function. As described in the question. Correct ?

Comment: yes, you used the dataURI function to generate $image and this $image you canuse in the url().as shown in the first code. The rest was mor as an explanation, if someone else searched for it.

Comment: @nbk, I managed to solve the problem. I forgot to add some information to the question. I added it now. Look at the last question code you will see the error to edit your answer.

Comment: you posted code with out showíng, what the variable contains.. $foto = dataURI ($ bin) or something similar. If you have trouble explaining ,write also in portuguese( se tu nao sabes explicar o que tu queres em inges, escreve tudo em protugues e em inges.

Comment: You are allowed to edit posts, that then get approved or declined.